# double linked list reverse function doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Everything else works except for the reverse function. The while loop doesn't end. I add in more details. Im so sorry. This is my second time getting help from Stack overflow.

This is the full code. Im not sure how to send the tail for reverse function.

Thank you so much. I truly appreciate all of your help.

```
    import math
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, val, next = None, prev = None):
            self.data = val
            self.next = next
            self.prev = prev

    class LinkedList:
        def __init__(self):
            self.head = None
            self.tail = None
            self.count = 0

        def StartInsert(self, val):
            newNode = Node(val)
            if self.count == 0:
                self.head = newNode
                self.tail = newNode
            else:
                self.head.prev = newNode
                newNode.next = self.head
                self.head = newNode
            self.count += 1

        def EndInsert(self, val):
            newNode = Node(val)
            if self.count == 0:
                self.head = newNode
                self.tail = newNode
            else:
                self.tail.next = newNode
                newNode.prev = self.tail
                self.tail = newNode
            self.count += 1

        def MiddleInsert(self, val):
            newNode = Node(val)
            if self.count == 0:
                self.head = newNode
                self.tail = newNode
            else:
                index = math.ceil(self.count/2)
                temp = self.head
                while index > 0:
                    temp = temp.next
                    index =- 1
                temp.next = Node(val, temp.next)
                temp.prev = Node(temp.prev.data, temp)
            self.count +=1

        def search(self, val):
            p = self.head
            while p is not None:
                if p.data == val:
                    return p
                p = p.next

        def delete(self, val):
            curNode = self.head
            while curNode != None:
                if curNode.data == val:
                    if curNode.prev != None:
                        curNode.prev.next = curNode.next
                    else:
                        self.head = curNode.next

                    if curNode.next != None:
                        curNode.next.prev = curNode.prev
                    else:
                        self.tail = curNode.prev

                    self.count -= 1

                curNode = curNode.next

        def reverse(self):
            temp = None
            current = self.head
            while current != None:
                temp = current.prev
                current.prev = current.next
                current.next = temp
                current = current.prev
            if temp:
                self.head = temp.prev
                self.tail= 


        def traverse(self):
            s = ""
            p = self.head
            while p is not None:
                s += str(p.data) + ' ';
                p = p.next
            print(s + "| count: " + str(self.count))


list = LinkedList()
list.EndInsert("a")
list.StartInsert("b")
list.StartInsert("c")
list.EndInsert("d")
list.MiddleInsert("c")
list.traverse()
print("_________________")
list.reverse()
list.traverse()
```

Comment: We need to see actual code that demonstrates the problem.  All you've shown us is some classes.  We need to see how you're _using_ those classes.

Comment: How are you creating Linked List and pushing items in it. Show the full code snippet.

Comment: I tried it out and I'm not getting an infinite loop on `reverse()`. Seems to work properly (except for not setting a new `self.tail`).

Comment: I have added my full code and the test code. Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: Was `index =- 1` supposed to be `index -= 1`?

Comment: And in the very next two lines, after you've selected the list's central node (only not really), you create two new nodes rather than just one (remember you created `newNode` earlier, but never used it), and neither new node has a `prev`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I see what you mean. Thank you. Is there a way you can show me what is the proper code should be for the middle insert

Comment: Use the `NewNode` you made, and properly insert it into the list. Make sure it has a proper `prev` and `next`, and do the same for both nodes it's connected to. Try using `reverse()` on a list you create without any `MiddleInsert()` and see what behavior you get. I tried `reverse()` on a list I created manually and it worked fine.

Comment: Issue with your code `self.tail =`. Remove this line

Comment: @skaul05 - That shows up six times. Which line do you mean?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 `self.tail =` in reverse function. It is causing error

Comment: @skaul05 - That's obviously a copy-paste mistake. It would result in a syntax error, not an infinite loop.